# Check if substring in PostgreSQL in where clause PostgreSQL, replacing XMLQuery and fnmatches in DB2

Tags: regex, xml, postgresql

We had a search in DB2 that had a part of where clause that went as follows "And XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('fn:matches($field,"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9][2]") PASSING VALUE  as "field" as integer) = 0

But this doesn't work with Postgres, so I was wondering how I could do the same? Have it in the where clause that it checks if part of a string is an interger and another part is string?

I believe part of it is getting the subtring from field, which is fine, but how do I check if that substring is an integer or string within the where clause?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: try to convert data using pg type conversion ::integer or ::text `select '12321312'::integer;` or 'select 12321312::text;'